# TextView Slider with Pagination in Android

Tags: java, android, pagination, textview, android-pageradapter

i need to Achieve something like this in android. i don't know how can i achieve this in android. i have already checked [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/) but it is a full screen slider with images and all. i just need a simple text slider with several slides in the middle of the screen not full screen.

[image]

i have already done that in my iOS app but i am wondering if i can do that in android app also. please do let me know how can i do this. Any Tutorial or code snippet would be great help. Thanks

here is my code so far.
in onCreate method:

```
//Set the pager with an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        List<Integer> objects = Arrays.asList(Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerCustomAdapter(objects));
        //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        ViewPagerWithIndicator viewPagerWithIndicator = (ViewPagerWithIndicator)findViewById(R.id.viewPagerWithIndicator);
        viewPagerWithIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

and xml

```
<com.kassisdion.library.ViewPagerWithIndicator
        app:arrow.enable="true"
        app:arrow.width="50dip"
        app:arrow.height="50dip"
        app:left_arrow.drawable="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_left"
        app:right_arrow.drawable="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_right"
        app:round.enable="true"
        app:round.size="15dip"
        app:round.drawable="@drawable/background_rounded"
        app:round.color.default="@android:color/white"
        app:round.color.selected="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerWithIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.kassisdion.library.ViewPagerWithIndicator>
```

Comment: Search on google , Its simple . You can get demo .

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting ?

Comment: "Type ViewPagerWithIndicator cannot be resolved to a type" and "Type ViewPagerCustomAdapter cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: have you add View pager gradle in your app gradle ?

Comment: i do not think so! how am i going to do that? i haven't added anything else.

Comment: i have posted my answer. check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [demo](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html).

You can put your view pager in center of activity with wrap_content and instead of ImageView you can put TextView with wrap_content .
It's easy and no other library is need to implement.

Comment: didnt work. i have already check this example. thanks